# Firebase cloud functions, not working .forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call the .forEach function in my Cloud functions and it even works, but it does not return what I need, I am trying to get the branch key and it just returns TRUE.

I cannot remove return from the second line (I think this is a mistake), because as soon as I remove it, an error appears.

```
return admin.database().ref('test/100').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  return snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
     return childKey;
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  return 'error';
})
```

My databse:

```
"test" : {
  "100" : {
    "ineedthis" : {
      "example" : "example"
    },
  },
}
```

Return:

```
True
```

I will be very grateful to everyone who helps.

Comment: You're trying to use `forEach` on an object.

Comment: @mwilson I'm a beginner, I don't fully understand how to do it right in my case ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `.forEach` on an object. That will not work. It looks like you can just return `snapshot.key` directly:

```
return admin.database().ref('test/100').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  return snapshot.key)); // or snapshot.ineedthis
}).catch(function(error) {
  return 'error';
})
```

Comment: And if there are 2 branches, how can I get the key of two branches?

Comment: I do not fully understand how everything works here, but I will definitely mark everything that is possible if you help me

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, snapshot.forEach returns a boolean, so it doesn't work like your typical js array iterator (which returns undefined).

What error is forcing you to `return` on the second line? And can you fix it by returning null after the iterator like this?

```
return admin.database().ref('test/100').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
         return childKey;
      });
      return null;
}).catch(function(error) {
  return 'error';
})
```

I wish I could comment, because mwilson is incorrect. The `forEach` function exists on the DataSnapshot object in this case. Hopefully you see this before marking that answer as correct.

Comment: Null is returned

Comment: That would indicate that snapshot has no keys to iterate through.

Could you try using `getValue()` instead of `once('value')`

Comment: Nevermind sorry, I don't think that will work. Have you read through this in the docs?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data